# test class is unable to read consul config

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have test code in which I want to read configurations from consul.The application.properties (src/main/resources) enables the consul config. And I have one POJO class name DBConfig (in src/main/java) which gets the configuration from consul. I have autowired the DBConfig in test class and when I'm running the unit test it is giving me nullpointerexception as it is not getting the values from consul.
How to handle the situation. Please help.

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="db")
@RefreshScope

public class DBConfig {

    private String jdbcURL;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String driverClass;

...getter setters.

}
```

Test Class---

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED,readOnly=false,rollbackFor=Exception.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes={DBConfig.class})
public class TestUserDao extends DBTestCase {

    @Autowired
    private DBConfig dbConfig;

    protected final Resource res = new ClassPathResource("actualDataSet.xml");

    @Bean
    @Profile("test")
    @RefreshScope
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(dbConfig.getDriverClass());
        dataSource.setUrl(dbConfig.getJdbcURL());
        dataSource.setUsername(dbConfig.getUsername());
        dataSource.setPassword(dbConfig.getPassword());

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public UserDAO userDAO(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        return new UserDAO(jdbcTemplate);
    }

    @Override
    protected IDataSet getDataSet() throws Exception {
        ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
        String file = classLoader.getResource("actualDataSet.xml").getFile();
        return new FlatXmlDataSetBuilder().build(new FileInputStream(file));
    }

    protected DatabaseOperation getSetUpOperation() throws Exception {
        return DatabaseOperation.REFRESH;
    }

    @Test
    public void insertTodo() throws Exception {

    }

    protected DatabaseOperation getTearDownOperation() throws Exception {
        return DatabaseOperation.DELETE;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be caused by usage of `MockitoJUnitRunner` class, which will not load `ApplicationContext` at startup, which means, your beans won't be accessible.

Once you will use `SpringRunner` class in `@RunWith()` annotation, Spring should be able to inject `DBConfig` bean.